# JavaScript Debounce - одинаково ли работают эти функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

Искал решения для debounce-функции в js и нашёл этот вариант:

```
function debounce1(func, ms) {
   let timeout;
   return function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), ms);
   };
}
```

Затем поэкспериментировал со способом вызова функции в setTimeout и получились эти два варианта, которые, кажется, работают также.

Есть ли отличия в работе этих функций?

```
// с ...args
function debounce2(func, ms) {
   let timeout;
   return function (...args) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => func(...args), ms);
   };
}

// с arguments
function debounce3(func, ms) {
   let timeout;
   return function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(func, ms, ...arguments);
   };
}
```

Comment: какие именно отличия имеются ввиду? Кроме способа вызова функции отличается только созданием обертки в первых двух случаях

Answer (score 0):

### Для начала

Дополню ваш вопрос ещё 1 вариантом. Рассмотрим как работают следующие 4 функции:

```js
function print(p1) {
  console.log(this, [...arguments]);
}

function debounce1(func, ms) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), ms);
  };
}

function debounce2(func, ms) {
  let timeout;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func(...args), ms);
  };
}

function debounce3(func, ms) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(func, ms, ...arguments);
  };
}

function debounce4(func, ms) {
  let timeout;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(func, ms, ...args);
  };
}

debounce1(print, 0)(1);
debounce2(print, 0)(1);
debounce3(print, 0)(1);
debounce4(print, 0)(1);
```

Получим результат:

```js
undefined, [0]
undefined, [0]
window, [0]
window, [0]
```

Вывод - у первой пары `this` отсутствует, а у `второй` ссылается на window.
Теперь рассмотрим по-подробнее.

### Анализ

Отметим, что `this` и `arguments` ссылаются на анонимную функцию.

- У функции нету `this` - отсюда и `undefined` в функции 1 и 2.
- Передавать аргументы в массив или получить с помощью `arguments` особого разницы нет. Поэтому у всех одинаковые аргументы. НО! Не советую использовать `arguments`. Запрещена в строгих контекстах (там, где использовано `"use strict"`)
  [image]
  Да и не советуют. Вот заметка на MDN:
  [image]
- И почему же мы получаем `window` в 3 и 4 функциях? Дело в том, что у функции переданного в `setTimeout` переписывается `this` на `window`. Проверить можем следующим кодом:

```js
function print() {
  console.log(this);
}

print(); // undefined
setTimeout(print); // window
```

### Результат

И почему же я добавил 4-ий вариант?
Потому что я советую именно его. В нем не используется `arguments` и в него передаюся значения как это задумано по `setTimeout`.

Comment: `Дело в том, что у функции переданного в setTimeout пере...` -- Я вызвал код и в обоих случаях получил `window`. Браузер Firefox.

Comment: Тот же самый код я запустил в локальном сервере на Chrome и Edge и получил `undefined` и `window`.

Answer (score -1):

**debounce2** лучший вариант

```
    // с ...args
    function debounce2(func, ms) {
       let timeout;
       return function (...args) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(() => func(...args), ms);
       };
   }
```

Comment: Обоснуйте).....